# Android development in Micromax funbook tablet

Tags: android

Is it possible to develop Android applications in Micromax funbook tablet?
Do I have to install any drivers to deploy android application in funbook?

Comment: If you can enable unknown sources in its settings menu, you should be able to deploy apks from an email attachment, or served by a web page with the appropriate mime type, or off of its external storage if you can get them there and install a file manager app and click on them.  But obviously having adb over usb or wifi is quite useful if you can get it set up.  The required usb driver would depend on the tablets VID

Comment: yes you need device adb interface software for debug testing or otherwise test copy apk file from pc to tablet sdcard and install apk file test it or send email and download attachment and install apk file now open your app!

Comment: Yes, you need to have adb for developing application in micromax funbook.

Comment: Can I directly deploy the application from Eclipse? Do I need any special Micromax drivers?

Comment: @sam any driver cd for micromax funbook tablet from buyer?

Comment: @sam you need adb interface software for micromax funbook tablet for  directly deploy the application from Eclipse!

Comment: thanks Dinesh!!! I am planning to buy Micromax tablet. So just wanted to know if Android development is possible or not

Comment: I got simple way. No need to root your device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found one from the first post on the following forum thread.

[Rooting Micromax Funbook easiest way!!!!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1662010)

I have downloaded only ADB_Driver.rar, installed it and is working for me.

You can **[download it from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1070541&d=1337427944)**

To check how to install driver go to [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) on Android's Official Developer website. And do not forget [to setup Android device for development](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up).