# Unable to adb to micromax funbook P300 tablet

Tags: android, drivers

Can anyone help me how can i connect micromax funbook P300 to my windowns 7  PC.

Tried updating tablet drivers using driver manager, but it was unable to find drivers for tablet online too.

Please let me know any drivers required for this to connect my micromax funbook to windows pc.

Comment: The answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305361/android-development-in-micromax-funbook-tablet) also has a reference to a rar file that contains a driver.  Seems to have worked for others there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the adb drivers only from [here...](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1662010)

After downloading follow these instructions:
**RightClick** on **MyComputer** > **Manage** > **Device Manager** > **RightClick** on **Android** > **Update Driver Software**
Goto **Browse my computer** and **enter the extracted location of above folder**..

Click continue Anyway if asked for installing non certified driver

Comment: Not supporting Windows8