# Run our application directly on Android device instead of emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application on version 4.0. While run this application on emulator it works perfectly. But convert it as a apk and then install it an micromax funbook the design pattern is differed from emulator. So that is very difficult to check in funbook every time with the apk.

So I decided to run the application directly in funbook instead of emulator. So I searched the web to see if there is any option configure our device to Eclipse. And I found that, the answer is yes, we can. But the problem is the hardware [driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) list provided by Google is didn't consider the micromax funbook. So then I found how to configure micromax funbook with eclipse from [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1662010) forum.

After I followed the instruction provided from that forum, my installation stopped at `select 2 to reboot into recovery` with `error: device not found` even I connected my device with `USB`. So my question is: is there anyway to configure micromax funbook with our development Eclipse?

Comment: may i know why this negative vote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305361/android-development-in-micromax-funbook-tablet see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Kill your android debugging bridge and again start adb.

```
 root@ndot-169:~/android-sdks/platform-tools# ./adb kill-server
 root@ndot-169:~/android-sdks/platform-tools# ./adb start-server
 * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
 * daemon started successfully *
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it show up when you run `adb devices`? Any other info on what is happening or what you have done already would also help.

There's no built-in driver with Eclipse as you say; but you can easily automate it by writing a Bash script that calls Ant and does the building, signing and aligning and then use ADB to push the APK and install it. If that just went over your head, don't worry: just look up the docs. Especially the Building section in the Getting Started tutorial on the [Dev website](http://developer.android.com).

Also, the forum page you linked to is for rooting the device. You don't need to do that to use it as a development device.

Comment: I guess if he wants to do usb debugging and hence go get going with eclipse he does

Answer (score 0):

You are going to root your device and did some mistake there and that's why the error in your funbook? You need to first correctly root your device. Then integration with the eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Just plug in your Micromax funbook to your computer via USB.

Enable the '**USB Debugging**' from

```
'System Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging
```

Then run your application from Eclipse and it will ask you for emulator to run on.
Select your cell phone as the emulator and the app will run directly on the Android device.